# When I run python file in VsCode modify message appear, Although I already installed Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I just changed my Windows and in VS code, when I run the Python file, it always gives me a modify [message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3x9S.png) and I can't do it at all.
Does anyone know the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to reinstall python3/modify/repair it, but in the bottom left corner it should show what python version it is trying to use and if you have that installed you should be good

also python3.9.5 is quite new so maybe you do not have that version installed

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have run the python installation program.

You can try to delete or rename the `.exe` file.

Comment: Yes. This version of Python that I used was 3.9. I deleted it and downloaded version 3.8 and it was fixed.